# Visual Studio 2015 PCL Can't Browse Nuget

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, portable-class-library

I've created a PCL in VS 2015. When i try to browse Nuget i get this error:

[nuget.org] The V2 feed at 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Search()?$filter=IsLatestVersion&searchTerm=''&targetFramework='portable46-net451+win81+wpa81'&includePrerelease=false&$skip=0&$top=26' returned an unexpected status code '500 Internal Server Error'.

My csproj contains:
    Profile151
    v4.6

In Postman, if i change the "portable46-net451" above to "net451" i can browse just fine.

A PCL made in VS 2013 doesnt seem to have this problem.

Comment: Install Fiddler, and compare the requests from 2013 and 2015. Compare headers.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the updated version of NuGet is broken. I got exactly the same result after upgrading to NuGet 3.4.1. Reverting back to 3.3 fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem last night in VS2017 15.9.11, and the solution in my case was to change .NET Framworks... even temporarily.

Details:
All VS2017 projects were stuck, and I was unable to browse NuGet packages through VS2017. However, this was only occurring on my computer at the office.... but again, it was occurring for all projects on my computer.
The error message included a note about .NET 4.6.1... which is what I was generally using for my projects. A co-worker was using .NET 4.7, and having no issue. I didn't have .NET 4.7 installed, but I already had 4.6.2 installed (though I hadn't yet used it in a project). So I upgraded to .NET framework 4.6.2 on that particular project (the one that originally had the issue), and the problem went away on all projects.... even the original project when I reload from version control with .NET Framework 4.6.1.
I can't even regenerate the error... at least so far.

So the problem seems to be solved in my case by switching .NET Frameworks.... even temporarily.